# How to load xml file through NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I found examples where `NSXMLParser` constructor uses URL, for example:

```
NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: (NSURL(string:"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss")))!
```

But I can't find how to use it with xml file from project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the path to a resource inside your application's bundle use `NSBundle`'s `pathForResource:ofType:` method, like:

```
 var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyFile", ofType: "xml")
```

You can create a file URL from the path and pass that to the `NSXMLParser`.

```
    var parser: NSXMLParser?
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyFile", ofType: "xml")
    if path != nil {
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    } else {
        NSLog("Failed to find MyFile.xml")
    }

    if parser != nil {
        // Do stuff with the parser here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version of accepted answer

```
var parser : XMLParser?
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "File", ofType: "xml") {
        parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

        if parser?.parse() ?? false {

        }else {
            print("Unable to parse")
        }

    }else {
        print("File read error")
    }
```